# Can we access HDFS file system and YARN scheduler in Apache Spark?

Tags: bigdata, apache-hadoop

We can access HDFS file system and YARN scheduler In the Apache-Hadoop. But Spark has a higher level of coding. Is it possible to access HDFS and YARN in Apache-Spark too?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

There are examples on spark official document: https://spark.apache.org/examples.html
Just put your HDFS file uri in your input file path as below (scala syntax).

```
val file = spark.textFile("hdfs://train_data")
```

Answer (score 6):

**HDFS**

Spark was built as an alternative to MapReduce and thus supports most of its functionality. In particular, it means that "Spark can create distributed datasets from any storage source supported by Hadoop, including your local file system, HDFS, Cassandra, HBase, Amazon S3, etc."[1](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#external-datasets). For most common data sources (like HDFS or S3) Spark automatically recognizes schema, e.g.:

```
val sc = SparkContext(...)
val localRDD = sc.textFile("file://...")
val hdfsRDD  = sc.textFile("hdfs://...")
val s3RDD    = sc.textFile("s3://...")
```

For more complicated cases you may need to work with lower-level functions like `newAPIHadoopFile`:

```
val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat], 
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result])
val customRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[MyCustomInputFormat], 
      classOf[MyCustomKeyClass],
      classOf[MyCustomValueClass])
```

But general rule is that if some data source is available for MapReduce, it can be easily reused in Spark.

**YARN**

Currently Spark supports 3 cluster managers / modes:

- **Standalone**
- **Mesos**
- **YARN**

Standalone mode uses Spark's own master server and works for Spark only, while YARN and Mesos modes aim to share same set of system resources between several frameworks (e.g. Spark, MapReduce, Impala, etc.). Comparison of YARN and Mesos may be found [here](http://www.quora.com/How-does-YARN-compare-to-Mesos), and detailed description of Spark on YARN [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/apache-spark-resource-management-and-yarn-app-models/).

And, in best traditions of Spark, you can switch between different modes simply by changing [master URL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/submitting-applications.html).